# How to get the same result of 'Recent' on Google Drive using the API?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am developing an android app using the Google Drive API.

Generally, I can get the files using the query API.

What I want to do now is make the same screen with 'Google Drive - Recent'.

But it looks like that there is no API for 'Recent' in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

So I am trying...

1. Get the all list except for Folder type.
2. Sort using the time field.

But the result doesn't same with the Web (Google Drive 'Recent').

My sorting logic is here:

```
fun sort(files: MutableList<com.google.api.services.drive.model.File>) {
    files.sortBy {
        val createdTime = it.createdTime?.value ?: 0
        val modifiedByMeTime = it.modifiedByMeTime?.value ?: 0
        val modifiedTime = it.modifiedTime?.value ?: 0
        val viewedByMeTime = it.viewedByMeTime?.value ?: 0
        val sharedWithMeTime = it.sharedWithMeTime?.value ?: 0

        maxOf(createdTime, modifiedByMeTime, modifiedTime, viewedByMeTime, sharedWithMeTime)
    }
}
```

How can I get the same result with web Google Drive 'Recent'?

One more thing...

My target customer is using "Shared Drive".
In this case, it is more complicated.

[image]

There are "never" items on the bottom of the list.
And the file list doesn't show the "date time".
But in my app, it shows the date.

[image]

I don't know how to use the API to get the same "Recent list".

Answer (score 0):

Try using the next parameters:

- **OrderBy:** lastviewedByMeDate desc `//Use "desc", otherwise default lastviewedByMeDate will show you the oldest files first`
- **q:** trashed = false and mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' `//So you also avoid files in trash and folders`

More info about search queries [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/search-files#query_search_examples)

I can't give you a coded example as I'm not into `kotlin`, but I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but, it is not helpful for me. There are some kinds of time attributes "viewedByMeTime, createdTime, modifiedTime, modifiedByMeTime, sharedTime, ...". I used them but my list doesn't same with google drive web screen.

Comment: you doesn't need to pass param , by default https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files returns recent files